# Whitney sum formula and Euler class

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

About the [Whitney sum formula and Euler class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class#Properties): If the fiber $F \to$ the base $X$ is an oriented, real vector bundle, then the Euler class of their direct sum is given by $e(E\oplus F)=e(E)\smile e(F).$ I do not quite understand the precise definition Lhs and Rhs formula : $$e(E\oplus F)=e(E)\smile e(F).$$

- Can one fill in more detail why this is true? (is that a cup product? how to define it precisely in this case?)
- Do we have similar statements about the Whitney sum formula for other  characteristic classes?
  (e.g. see the link [Whitney sum formula for Pontryagin classes are rather different?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222576/whitney-sum-formula-for-pontryagin-classes-i) $p(E\oplus F) = p(E)\cdot p(F)$ modulo 2-torsion

Comment: The takeaway from my answer below is that if you have a question about characteristic classes, you should first consult Milnor and Stasheff.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is cup product. This property of the Euler class is proved in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes* on page $100$.

If $w$ denotes the total Stiefel-Whitney class, then $w(E\oplus F) = w(E)w(F)$; this is proved on pages $92$ and $93$.

If $p$ denotes the total Pontryagin class, then $p(E\oplus F) = p(E)p(F)$ modulo two-torsion (i.e. $2(p(E\oplus F) - p(E)p(F)) = 0$); this is proved on page $175$.

If $E$ and $F$ are complex vector bundles and $c$ denotes the total Chern class, then $c(E\oplus F) = c(E)c(F)$; this is proved on pages $164 - 166$.

Comment: cap product ->  cup product

Comment: @annieheart: Fixed.

Comment: Indeed. It's now about 40 years since I first looked into M&S; I recently re-read much of it, as a kind of entertainment, and it's astoundingly well-written. I wish that the proof of the axioms for S-W classes didn't just delegate to corresponding facts about the Steenrod squares, which I've never really understood, but aside from that, it's pretty much perfect.